# unable to subdivide the mesh

Tags: modeling

I select the mesh to unsubdivide, but this method is not doing working, what am I doing incorrect?

[image]

Comment: On that object, try Mesh > Cleanup > Limited Dissolve.

Comment: Have a look here for more info https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155453/unsubdivide-doesnt-work

Comment: Un-Subdivide will work on quads, not tris

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simplify the objects geometry and it is all triangles, one option is to use the Decimate modifier set to Planar.

Both object in the screenshot are have the same geometry but the one in the front has the Decimate modifier on it.

[image: Decimate]